# Python Dataframe: Assign Values to a column based on other column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have df with three columns `a`,`b`,`c`.I want change `NaN` values in column `b`. Eg: For the value of `123` in column `a`, column `b` has both `abc` and `NaN`. I want both to change to `abc`.

```
raw_data = {'a': [123, 123, 456, 456], 
        'b': [np.nan,'abc','def',np.nan],
           'c':[np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a', 'b','c'])

    a   b   c
0   123 NaN NaN
1   123 abc NaN
2   456 def 0
3   456 NaN NaN
```

My expected Output

```
df


    a   b   c
1   123 abc NaN
0   123 abc NaN
2   456 def 0
3   456 def NaN
```

What i have tried:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['a','b']).fillna(method='ffill')
```

But this changes the `column c` also.

Output from above:

```
a   b   c
1   123 abc NaN
0   123 abc NaN
2   456 def 0
3   456 def 0
```

How do i use `ffill` for a particular column or any other approaches recommended?

Sample Data 2:

```
raw_data = {'a': [123, 123, 456, 456,789,np.nan], 
        'b': [np.nan,'abc','def',np.nan,np.nan,'ghi'],
           'c':[np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a', 'b','c'])

           a    b   c
    0   123.0   NaN NaN
    1   123.0   abc NaN
    2   456.0   def 0
    3   456.0   NaN NaN
    4   789.0   NaN NaN
    5   NaN     ghi abc
```

Expected Output

```
           a    b   c
    0   123.0   abc NaN
    1   123.0   abc NaN
    2   456.0   def 0
    3   456.0   def NaN
    4   789.0   NaN NaN
    5   NaN     ghi abc
```

Comment: if you want to change only `b` then do only `b`: `df['b'] = df.sort_values(by=['a','b']).fillna(method='ffill')['b']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new updated data, you should use `Series.map`:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].first()).fillna(df['b'])

       a    b    c
0  123.0  abc  NaN
1  123.0  abc  NaN
2  456.0  def  0.0
3  456.0  def  NaN
4  789.0  NaN  NaN
5    NaN  ghi  NaN
```

---

**Old answer**

Use `groupby` with `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].ffill().bfill()

     a    b    c
0  123  abc  NaN
1  123  abc  NaN
2  456  def  0.0
3  456  def  NaN
```

Comment: It worked. Can you check the edit. For another sample data.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum How would you like the output for row `789.0   NaN` be?

Comment: same as it is - `789.0 NaN NaN`. Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The `fillna` function applies to all the `DataFrame`. 
One solution is to truncate your `DataFrame` in order to have only the columns you want to modify, and apply only to it the `fillna` function, then add back the other column:

```py
 df_ab = df.loc[:,["a","b"]]
 df_ab = df_ab.sort_values(by=['a','b']).fillna(method='ffill')
 df_ab["c"] = df["c"]
```